# If filenames exist, then skip to next in For statement

Tags: python-3.x

I have a simple script that runs through a directory and renames the files.

Junk.Old.txt > NEW_FILE_DATE_TIME_Junk.txt

If the files match, it works perfectly.

Problem I have is if a file has already been renamed, and I have a new file(s) I want to rename, I get an error.  So if I have two files in the new format and one to rename, it fails with below and doesn't rename the old file.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./rename.py", line 17, in <module>
    f_job, f_ext = f_name.split('.print')
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Obviously it is seeing the already renamed files and quitting.   So what do I need in order for it to check if file format already exists, skip to next until all files are renamed?

```
#!/bin/python3

import os

 os.chdir('/my/folder/')

for f in os.listdir():
    f_name, file_ext = os.path.splitext(f)
    f_job, f_ext = f_name.split('.Old')
    f_attrib1 = "NEW"
    f_attrib2 = "FILE"
    import time
    new_name = '{}_{}_{}_{}_{}{}'.format(f_attrib1, f_attrib2, time.strftime("%Y%m%d"), time.strftime("%H%M%S"), f_job, file_ext)

    os.rename(f, new_name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to ignore files that don't have ".Old" in them, you can add this above your split:

```
if '.Old' not in f_name:
    continue
```

Comment: Took a little bit to get the formatting to work, but it works exactly as I want it to now. TY.  Note, one little space in one line can mess up the entire thing.